# Java file reading

Tags: java, file, io, readfile

I am trying to read file in Java. The structure of the file is as follows

```
** <br/>
f=1100<br/>
d=111<br/>
e=1101<br/>
b=101<br/>
c=100<br/>
a=0<br/>
**

11001100110011001100110111011101110111011101110111011101100100100100100100100100100100100
101011011011011011011011011011011011011011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

It starts with ** , then there is some stuff which I just want to read. There there is ** again and a blank line and the some more data. 
I know how to read data but I am not able to handle how to read the data that is only between **

Uptill now I have done this

```
 File toRead=new File("output.txt");
 FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(toRead);
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(fis);
 String currentLine;
 sc.delimiter = "**";
 while(sc.hasNext()){

     currentLine=sc.nextLine();
     system.out.println(sc.next());



  }
 fis.close();
```

Comment: Is the string between your data (here `**`) always the same?

Comment: You read the ** store all the lines until you read ** again. Seems pretty clear cut to me

Comment: I just edited to show what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Maverick YOu should read file line by line and check whether line starts from `**` `( contain())`and then store that in some array of bufferedreader till next `**`

Comment: doesn't the File reading stuff have to be within a try catch block?

Comment: @Smit : I tried to do this but is not working  while(sc.nextLine().contains("**")){  line = sc.nextLine(); //print it}

Comment: @Maverick Take a look at following question. This is kind of similar but you should also read file correctly to achieve your goal. [--->>read data from a file in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889181/read-data-from-a-file-in-java/13904260#13904260)  and [--->> Reading a file line by line using the Scanner class](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/file-input-output-tutorials/339-reading-file-line-line-using-scanner-class.html)

Comment: I am not sure if my explanation of file structure was clear. I have just edited and pasted the sample file. I want to read eveything only between the **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
File f = new File("output.txt");
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        String line = "";
        while(s.hasNext()){
            line=s.nextLine();
            if(line.startsWith("**")){
                line=line.replaceAll("[**]", "");
                System.out.println(line);
                while((line=s.nextLine())!=null){  
                    if(!(line.endsWith("**")))
                        System.out.println(line);
                    else if(line.endsWith("**")){
                           line=line.replaceAll("[**]","");
                        System.out.println(line);
                        break;
                    }

                }
            } 
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: This is good for following  line  `**abcd xyz**` . I think you means to say `||` .

Comment: I am not sure if my explanation of file structure was clear. I have just edited and pasted the sample file. I want to read eveything only between the **

Comment: This works however it also includes the **. I only want the part in between the **.

Comment: @Maverick This is quite good answer. YOu have to make lil modifications only and you are good to go.. and +1 @ Azad Omer

Comment: Ok, See the answer it's final one :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are asking how to parse.  Parsing has its foundation in push down automaton (PDA).  To do a truly generic parser, you need to understand it.  Back in the day lexx and yak were used to do just that, they generated C code for parsers.  There may be something similar for java.

Failing all that, you will simply have to hard code your parser:

```
while(sc.hasNext()){
 currentLine=sc.nextLine();
 system.out.println(sc.next());  //Great for debugging
 if(currentLine.equals("**") {   //use a constant instead
   newRecord = true;
   continue;
 } else if(currentLine.equals(???) {
   //set some values
 }  //etc
```

}

Your delimiter represents a state transition and you will need to keep track of that in your code...which of course is address by PDA.  It is much easier if you understand states, tokens, and transitions.

Comment: I am not sure if my explanation of file structure was clear. I have just edited and pasted the sample file. I want to read eveything only between the **

Comment: If you want to pay me, I'd be happy to write it for you.  If you are looking for general help, I think I answered your question.  BTW I am expensive.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the only problem is that you want to use a delimiter but didn't put it in properly.

```
File toRead=new File("output.txt");
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(toRead);
Scanner sc=new Scanner(fis);
String currentLine;
sc.useDelimiter("\\*\\*");
while(sc.hasNext()){

 currentLine=sc.nextLine();
 System.out.println(sc.next());



 }
fis.close();
```

You have to call the useDelimiter with Regex and you need to escape the *. So your regex is `\*\*` (one \ before a * to escape it)

Because useDelimiter accepts a String you have to escape the \ so `\\ -> \` and `\\*\\* -> \*\*`

Comment: I tried using the delimiter pattern which you suggested. However it also reads the file after the delimiter

Comment: Try to copy the code i wrote into a main-Method and let it read a file like you wrote